# How elements are stored within Hashmap in Ada?

Tags: hashmap, ada, ada2012

I would like to know if the Element_Type object is stored within a Hashmap in Ada (either a normal Hashmap, indefinite or bounded) as is or it is only stored a pointer to the instance of the real Element_Type object, that is, I want to be sure that the elements are not copied into the hashmap.

Comment: No, elements are copied into the map, but they can be updated in-place when they've been added.

Comment: If you are using the GNAT Ada toolset, the whole run-time is itself written in Ada.
From GNAT Studio, you can study how it is implemented with a few right-clicks.

Comment: Since it’s possible to store the value of an expression, there’s no chance of having a pointer to the external object; there needn’t be an external object.

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: @JeffreyR.Carter I'm writting an observer design pattern and I want to store singletons of the observers, but if the elements are being copied I could run out of memory and I could not have the last version of the observer which I have to notify, so I think I have to store the pointers to the observers class-wide concrete observer in order to achieve that.

Comment: Many of the "design patterns" aren't design patterns at all; they're work-arounds for the limitations of the languages used by the authors. For example, the singleton pattern is a work-around for the lack of modules; in Ada, a singleton is simply a package. In my experience, following the design pattern approach usually results in poor Ada.

Comment: As additional examples of @JeffreyR.Carter's point, examine these [_Software Patterns Implemented in Ada_](http://adapower.com/index.php?Command=Class&ClassID=Patterns&Title=Patterns)